# NextJS - serving static content from .next

Tags: next.js

NextJS serves static assets from the `public` directory.

However, I've got a Webpack loader (`responsive-loader`) that generates images as a part of the build pipeline, and the images land in the `.next` directory. How do I serve these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `outputPath` as the path to the `public` folder, this will tell Webpack to save the assets in `public` folder instead of `.next`